# What are zeroes in $\mathbb{Q}\otimes M$

Tags: tensor-products

If regard $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and M another $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then $q\otimes m$ is zero in $\mathbb{Q}\otimes M$ iff q or m is zero, how to proof it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is false - consider the element $1\otimes \overline{1}$ of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. We have
$$1\otimes \overline{1}=(2\cdot \tfrac{1}{2})\otimes \overline{1}=2(\tfrac{1}{2}\otimes\overline{1})=\tfrac{1}{2}\otimes (2\cdot \overline{1})=\tfrac{1}{2}\otimes\overline{0}=\tfrac{1}{2}\otimes(0\cdot\overline{0})=0(\tfrac{1}{2}\otimes\overline{0})=0$$
In fact, every element of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is the zero element. In other words, $\mathbb{Q}\otimes(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})=0$.